# Alternatives to replace ExtJS 1.2

Tags: javascript, jsp, extjs

Im thinking in replace ExtJS 1.2 in a project that does not work in IE9 (only works in compatibility view and is so slowly  loading a tree). What JS frameworks are better (and trying to replacing as little posible the code?

I see ExtJS 4 but has changed a lot compared with ExtJS 1.2